# Typo3 best practices - general variables

Tags: typo3

What is the best way to allow backend users to edit variables?

For example, I have a TYPO3 that sends out various e-Mail notifications and I want the backend users to be able to globally change the recipients. I started with template constants, until I found out, that backend users cannot edit the "template" module.

So what would be the best way to achieve this? I'm using Typo3 8.7.7

Answer (score 1):

I would create a configuration record which can be edited by the backend users.

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to include one file from fileadmin/ into the constants definition of typoscript. This file editors could change. **But that could be a security risk, as the editors could define any constants.**

the next option would be to define additional fields to the pages record, where these values could be set by any editor. In typoscript you access the field (maybe with `slide = -1`, so the value needs to be set just once)

another option: add these fields to a (special?) CE (ContentElement).

last option: use std CEs (e.g.HTML-content) at special pages or columns and use the content field (bodytext). (HTML-content has the advantage that the bodytext field is stored unmodified.)

Cleanest and leanest option would be option two (additional fields to table 'pages'). Option three and four are possible with pure typoscript, but you need to use CONTENT or RECORD object. If you use fix uids: remember that your editors might delete the CE and add a new CE with the same content (but another uid)

---

Addition:

As @Thomas-Löffler in his answer said:
you also can add a new kind of record/table, where an editor can insert or change the global values. Handling is like pages or tt_content. you can differ if your records are global (pid = 0, or special storage page) or dependent on page tree (rootpath), so you can have differnt values for different page subtrees.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer! I will analyse these options and try to find what works best for me.

Answer (score 0):

I like Thomas‘ answer for providing a dedicated place to store the configuration option instead of putting it e.g. to `pages` because your configuration option is not bound to a page context.

Nonetheless for me personally it feels a bit odd to create a dedicated table for it. A table that would never hold more than one record.

That leads me to the conclusion that a key-value storage would be the right thing to use. Fortunately, TYPO3 ships [System Registry](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/SystemRegistry/Index.html). The only downside is that there‘s no interface for it so you‘d have to come up with your own forms to fill it. That‘s much easier if you go with Thomas‘ solution…

Answer (score 0):

A clean and easy way is setting up a backend module with a form to set the email addresses. 
Then you can grant the access right to a specific group or user and they are ready to go.